# Xcode 5 diff files that aren't in versioning system

Tags: xcode, xcode5, diff

Xcode 5 has a nice diff system. But for the life of me, I cannot get it to diff two files that aren't in a repository. I just want to use it to compare any two arbitrary files, but when I open one file, and go to the version editor button, the two half windows say: "no editor"

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can't. Xcode is only giving you a visualization of the output of the git [diff command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), which as far as I know only works for source controlled files within the repo.

Comment: Who is voting this down? Did they know the answer and though it obvious? Did they not know the answer, and though it wasn't possible? Were they upset I was asking a question about Xcode, and they don't like Xcode? What is up with that.

Comment: Excellent question.  It was 100% what I was asking and an excellent answer is below (File Merge utility).  The "you can't" comment is not an answer - besides, it is wrong.  Voted +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose Xcode > Open Developer Tool > FileMerge from the menu bar and you'll get an app that can show you a comparison view much like the one in the Xcode version editor.

Comment: Great thanks. Odd that they don't allow this behavior directly without GIT.